# Ошибка OSError: error in opening %filename% for reading из-за кириллицы в пути

Tags: python, windows, кодировка, ос

Мне требуется архивировать несколько путей на машине с Windows. Для архивации использую pyminizip, т.к. он позволяет установить пароль на архив. С помощью pathlib получаю список всех файлов по каждому из нужных путей, объединяю их в один список, далее преобразую в два списка строк - полный путь к файлу и путь до родительской папки - и затем, пытаюсь архивировать с помощью pyminizip.compress_multiple. На этапе архивирования возникала ошибка  `SystemError: <build-in function compress_multiple> returned NULL without setting an error`.

Упрощая свой код, в итоге пришел к тому, что проблема кроется в файлах, в чьих полных именах есть кириллица. Сделал тестовую структуру файлов и пытаюсь на ней победить кириллицу.

```
D:
├─── test
│   ├─── latin_only
│   │   ├─── 1.txt
│   │   ├─── 2.txt
│   │   └─── ы.txt
│   │
│   ├─── с кириллицей
│   │   ├─── 11.txt
│   │   ├─── 22.txt
│   │   └─── ыы.txt
│   │
│   ├─── 111.txt
│   ├─── 222.txt
│   └─── ыыы.txt
...
```

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import pyminizip


path_to_arc = Path('D:/test')
filepaths_to_arc = [p for p in path_to_arc.rglob('*') if p.is_file() and not p.stem.startswith('~$')]
list_file_path_and_prefix = {p.as_posix():p.parent.as_posix() for p in filepaths_to_arc} 

# list_file_path_and_prefix вывел в консоль и разбил на два объекта: все файлы и файлы без кириллицы pprint(list_file_path_and_prefix)
all_files = {'D:/test/111.txt': 'D:/test',
 'D:/test/222.txt': 'D:/test',
 'D:/test/latin_only/1.txt': 'D:/test/latin_only',
 'D:/test/latin_only/2.txt': 'D:/test/latin_only',
 'D:/test/latin_only/ы.txt': 'D:/test/latin_only',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/11.txt': 'D:/test/с кириллицей',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/22.txt': 'D:/test/с кириллицей',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/ыы.txt': 'D:/test/с кириллицей',
 'D:/test/ыыы.txt': 'D:/test'}

only_latin = {'D:/test/111.txt': 'D:/test',
 'D:/test/222.txt': 'D:/test',
 'D:/test/latin_only/1.txt': 'D:/test/latin_only',
 'D:/test/latin_only/2.txt': 'D:/test/latin_only'}

try:
    pyminizip.compress_multiple(list(only_latin.keys()), list(only_latin.values()), 'D:/test/arc_latin_only.zip', '1234', 2)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
try:
    pyminizip.compress_multiple(list(all_files.keys()), list(all_files.values()), 'D:/test/arc_cyrillic.zip', '1234', 2)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

В итоге arc_latin_only.zip создается без проблем, а при создании второго возникает ошибка `OSError: error in opening D:/test/latin_only/ы.txt`

При этом сам файл без проблем читается через `with open('D:/test/latin_only/ы.txt', 'r') as f`, то есть windows понимает такое написание пути

Упрощал код до такого:

```
import pyminizip

only_latin = ['D:/test/111.txt', 'D:/test/222.txt', 'D:/test/latin_only/1.txt', 'D:/test/latin_only/2.txt']
all_files = ['D:/test/111.txt',
 'D:/test/222.txt',
 'D:/test/latin_only/1.txt',
 'D:/test/latin_only/2.txt',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/11.txt',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/22.txt',
 'D:/test/с кириллицей/ыы.txt',
 'D:/test/ыыы.txt']
pyminizip.compress_multiple(only_latin, [], 'D:/test/arc_only_latin.zip', '1234', 2)
pyminizip.compress_multiple(all_files, [], 'D:/test/arc_cyrillic.zip', '1234', 2)
```

и та же самая ошибка `OSError: error in opening D:/test/с кириллицей/11.txt`
Замена / на \ ничего не дала - ошибка та же

Попробовал сделать через os.walk

```
import pyminizip
import os

path = 'D:/test'
os.chdir(path)
src_files = []
dest_paths = []
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        src_files.append(os.path.join(folder, file))
        dest_paths.append(folder)

pyminizip.compress_multiple(src_files, dest_paths, 'D:/test/test.zip', '1234', 2)
```

В таком варианте ошибка `OSError: error in opening .\ыыы.txt`

Как можно решить проблему с кириллицей в путях в этом модуле?

Comment: как вариант - попробовать пути перекодировать из utf-8 либо в win1251 либо в cp866

Comment: Можешь поконкретнее написать? 'D:/test/ыыы.txt'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1251') ничего не даёт